# subadditivity and continuity at zero implies continuity at all points

Tags: functional-analysis

If $p$ is a subadditive functional on a normed space $X$ and is continious at $0$ and $p(0)=0$. To show $p$ is continious for all $x \in X$.

This is a problem from Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis. I have to show if $(x_{n}) \longrightarrow x$  then $p(x_{n}) \longrightarrow p(x)$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

$$p(x-y)\leq p(x) +p(-y) $$ and $$p(x) =p(x-y +y )\leq p(x-y) +p(y) $$ hence $$|p(x) -p(x-y)|\leq \max\{ p(y) ,p(-y) \} .$$
Now if $$x_n \to x_0 $$ then $$|p(x_n) -p(x_0)|\leq \max\{ p(x_n -x_0) ,p(x_0 -x_n) \} \to 0.$$

Comment: It helps, thanks